# Getting multiple nonces output on custom WooCommerce registration page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, twig, woocommerce-theming

I have created a custom WooCommerce registration page and have this section:

```
<div class="field submit">
    {{ fn('wp_nonce_field', 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce') }}
    <button type="submit" class="button btn" name="register" value="Create Account">Create Account</button>
</div>
```

However, when it is output to the page I get this:

```
<div class="field submit">
    <input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-register-nonce" name="woocommerce-register-nonce" value="05a274c0b9">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/create-account/">
    <input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-register-nonce" name="woocommerce-register-nonce" value="05a274c0b9">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/create-account/">
    <button type="submit" class="button btn" name="register" value="Create Account">Create Account</button>
</div>
```

However if I comment out this line:

```
{{ fn('wp_nonce_field', 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce') }}
```

Then I get no nonce.

So for some reason it is generating multiple and duplicate nonces, any idea why and how I can prevent this?

FYI - this is the only registration form on the page. Also, I am using the Twig templating system, so if you were wondering what `{{ fn('wp_nonce_field') }}` does, it's just running the function followed by the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it with the below change:

```
{{ fn('wp_nonce_field', 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce', true, false) }}
```

`wp_nonce_field` echos the result, so I changed it so it returned it by setting the last parameter to `false` so it wouldn't echo, as putting values between `{{  }}` in Twig already echos the data.